# How to avoid negative values in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
double totTax = double.parse(nontax_amt) - double.parse(tax);
        String tottax = totTax.toString();
        double igst = double.parse(igstper) / 100 * double.parse(tottax);
        double cAmt = double.parse(widget.itemDetailsList[position].cgstRate) /
                      100 *double.parse(tottax);
          double total =totTax +igst +cAmt;
          String totamt = tot.toString();
```

I am calculating some double values called totTax,igst,cAmt and it's giving values with negative sign. I want the positive answer instead of negative values, meaning whatever value I try to calculate it should not give answer with negative sign.

Note: Because of negative sign the value of total is becoming wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `abs()` which converts any value to positive or absolute. Just like this,

```
String totamt = tot.abs().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `abs()` method

```
double totTax = (double.parse(nontax_amt) - double.parse(tax)).abs();
double igst = (double.parse(igstper) / 100 * double.parse(tottax)).abs();
double cAmt = (double.parse(widget.itemDetailsList[position].cgstRate) /
                      100 *double.parse(tottax)).abs();
```